# What tense to use when a subjunctive mood sentence has nested clauses

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions, subjunctives, irrealis-mood

Consider the following sentence:

> If I knew what the problem ___, I would be able to help you better.

Should the verb be "is" or "was"?

Answer (score 0):

That sentence is in the *irrealis mood*, and is commonly known as an "unreal conditional". In irrealis mood broadly, it is always correct to use a verb tense that is one *tense* in the past from the *time* they represent.

So in your sentence, the time is *present*, so it's definitely correct to use the *simple past* "was" to indicate it is unreal.

Sometimes we can also use the *same tense as the time* in unreal grammar. This is possible (never required) when the verb refers to a general fact or a long-term state. For example:

> If I knew what *his job is*, I would be able to help you better.

In that context, his job is a long-term state, so "is" is acceptable. In your example sentence, however, "the problem" is probably just a problem now, not a stable, long-term state, so only "was" is correct, not "is".

Comment: I don't see the relevance here of Irrealis. Present-day English does not have an inflectional mood system; it was lost in earlier stages of the language. Leaving aside the modal auxiliaries, all that remains is what grammarians now call irrealis "were", which is limited to 1/3 sg forms of BE, as in "If he were in love with her, he'd change his job".

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Can you suggest a grammar book that deals with such nuanced details?

Comment: @BillJ That might be true for the term "irrealis" in current academic linguistics, but this is how it's commonly used in TESL.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "current academic linguistics". At any level of learning, it's obvious that there is not a single verb in English that is inflected for mood. The only odd-ball is irrealis "were" (or the ill-named past subjunctive) which is limited to 1/3 sg forms of BE. It's an untidy relic of an earlier system.

Comment: @BillJ I don't want contested definitions to to distract anyone from my answer, which isn't about the meaning of those words. If I remove the word "irrealis" and replace it with, say, "unreal", would that resolve the issue?